# (m1 macbook) installing redis php extension results in wrong architecture, how can I get an arm64 architecture of redis.so

Tags: redis

I'm trying to use redis to broadcast events on laravel but php isn't able to load this extension due to wrong architecture.
I used `pecl install redis` to install the extension and I'm wondering if there's a flag I can pass to build/install using a diff architecture (arm64)

`PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'redis.so'`

```
no suitable image found.  Did find: 
redis.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

running `lipo -info redis.so` results in `redis.so is architecture: x86_64`
But I think my machine (m1 macbook) requires an arm64 extension. (as I see other .so files with the correct architecture.

Any help on how I can create this would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried to download the tar file, extract and make, but on make test, the device actually crashes during the process, or overheats and just doesn't finish executing make test.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the terminal in x86 mode on top of Rosetta 2.

1. Go to where the terminal application is located in the finder (Applications/Utilities/Terminal)
2. Click it once so it highlights then press *cmd + I* to open up the information tab.
3. Hit this:

[image: open using rosetta button pic]

to open the terminal in the Rosetta mode.

4. Open the terminal

This doesn't always work for the nature of some programs but it is worth giving it a shot.